# laravel react command run dev not working

Tags: reactjs, laravel

```
    C:\wamp64\www\want>npm run dev

> @ dev C:\wamp64\www\want
> npm run development


> @ development C:\wamp64\www\want
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

The system cannot find the path specified.
events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js ENOENT
    at notFoundError (C:\Users\coolm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
    at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\coolm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\coolm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:12)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\coolm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:30:37)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:12)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\coolm\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-09-18T16_07_49_646Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\coolm\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-09-18T16_07_49_686Z-debug.log

C:\wamp64\www\want>
```

I'm trying to hook up my Laravel application with React. I followed the step of running the command "php artisan preset react" but after I was instructed to run npm install & run dev. I keep getting the following error. Does anyone have a similar problem?

Comment: Run `npm install` by itself and see if there are errors.

Comment: Yeah, I did that. No luck

Answer (score 0):

Try doing full reset:

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json yarn.lock
npm cache clear --force
npm install
```

Comment: I used PowerShell instead of CMD and it works perfectly!